# Does playing in the in-game offline mode unlock achievements?

Tags: pc, achievements, borderlands-2

In Borderlands 2, when playing in-game and hitting <kbd>Esc</kbd>, under `Network Options` there are several modes.

- Online Friends Only
- Online Invite Only
- Online Public
- LAN
- Offline

**Will `Offline` allow you to earn achievements?** I am talking specifically about the in-game option, I am not talking about Steam's offline mode, which is something different.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, you will still unlock achievements if you switch to Offline mode inside *Borderlands 2*. Achievements for Borderlands 2 are generally never disabled.

The only way to miss out on achievements is due to synchronization errors with Steam itself.